# Polymer paper-dialog-scrollable. scroll to the end

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I use paper-dialog-scrollable.

```
 <paper-dialog-scrollable>
 </paper-dialog-scrollable>
```

How can I make this section to scroll to the end? I looked in the api and their is nothing that I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the paper-dialog-scrollable some id (e.g mypaperscrollable) and

```
this.mypaperscrollable.$.scrollable.scrollTop = someValueHere
```

You could get the relative position of the last element inside your scrollable and use that as the value for scrollTop

Comment: the someValue is an element ? or I have to write pixels?

Comment: You have to set it to the pixels amount you want it scrolled to.

Comment: Setting it to some value higher than the height of the scrollable  would ensure it's scrolled to the bottom