# Instruct paper-dialog-scrollable to scroll to bottom

Tags: polymer-2.x, polymerfire

I have a paper-dialog-scrollable which is filled with a dom-repeat from a firebase-query. Everything works fine, except paper-dialog-scrollable doesn't scroll to the bottom when firebase adds an entry to the array.
I managed to set a callback whenever the array gets a new entry (basically with an observer on the spliced array, not on the array).
So how do I instruct paper-dialog-scrollable to scroll to bottom from that callback ?
I saw solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235079/polymer-paper-dialog-scrollable-scroll-to-the-end) which don't seem to work.
Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235079/polymer-paper-dialog-scrollable-scroll-to-the-end) you provided, give the `paper-dialog-scrollable` some id (e.g `pds`) and then add the following code:

`this.$.pds.$.scrollable.scrollTop = this.$.pds.$.scrollable.scrollHeight;`

> An element's `scrollTop` value is a measurement of the distance from the
>   element's top to its topmost visible content. When an element's
>   content does not generate a vertical scrollbar, then its `scrollTop`
>   value is 0. [Learn more about scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).
>
> The element's `scrollHeight` read-only property is a measurement of
>   the height of an element's content, including content not visible on
>   the screen due to overflow. [Learn more about scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

I have made a demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/JIZEdd6NoBBnwndbQuFA?p=preview.

Comment: Your Plunkr works great. Thanks! I have a question, though : paper-dialog-scrollable should be inside a Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior implementing element, according tot the [docs](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-scrollable). Am I missing something here ?

Comment: In addition, for this to work in a dynamic data feeding of the scrolling element (firebase in my case), I had to wait until next render once the array mutation callback is triggered : `Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => { this.$.scrolly.$.scrollable.scrollTop = this.$.scrolly.$.scrollable.scrollHeight; });`

Comment: To be thorough, Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender can be replaced by forcing the render of the dom-repeat element bound to firebase result array. Anyway, IMO, paper-dialog-scrollable should automagically scroll to last, or propose a way to make it happen, instead of forcing us to access and set sub-properties...

Comment: `PaperDialogBehavior` makes an element a material design dialog. So, if you want material design you can implement that.